# Encryption with Eval on PHP

Tags: decode

need help all,
now I have code like

```
function encode64($text){
    $text_encode = base64_encode($text);
    $text_encode = str_replace("=","_",$text_encode);
    if(strlen($text_encode)%2==1) $text_encode=$text_encode."*";
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($text_encode)/2;$i++){
        $result = $result.substr($text_encode,$i,1);
        $result = $result.substr($text_encode,strlen($text_encode)-$i-1,1);
    }
    return strrev($result);
}

function decode64($text){
    $text_decode = strrev($text);
    for($i=0;$i<strlen($text_decode)/2;$i++){
        $raw_result = $raw_result.substr($text_decode,$i*2,1);  
    }
    for($i=strlen($text_decode)/2;$i>0;$i--){
        $raw_result = $raw_result.substr($text_decode,$i*2-1,1);
    }
    if(substr($raw_result,strlen($raw_result)-1,1)=="*"){
        for($i=0;$i<strlen($text_decode)-1;$i++){
            $result = $result.substr($text_decode,$i,1);    
        }
        return base64_decode($result);
    }else return base64_decode($raw_result);
}
```

this is using encode64 :    LnCQd3ybbv2J930JJsyckC7dbzX9lGzagasuiUIHUIYIUYUISydiuahsdoijpojOIJIOIoiewSJIODcsWFx2fYcv2xV2sJZoWQN30YXl25RmibKvCNd23XasXFJ3hcX531NG5Ic93ARilbbvSNcGsJI7CkRyjJbh2R4npcbh3tIWgYZKG9lSlYKpGN1X5Qcn3gFCsdXl2NV3yXclm592ybK6CVkWpbOp3RJ3lXd0HxVWydbhiZAWkZYk299VuZO0wF_G_Z

and who can give me result
why can't read full code, I just can read like below:
http://i60.tinypic.com/2euomzq.png

can give me any solution because I need full code.

Comment: I really don't understand the question. What are we supposed to do with the encoded string to provided? And why is the URL you entered there?

Comment: @ItaiBar-Haim I mean this encode64 : LnCQd3ybbv2J930JJsyckC7dbzX9lGzagasuiUIHUIYIUYUISydiuahsdoijpojOIJIOIoiewSJIODcsWFx2fYcv2xV2sJZoWQN30YXl25RmibKvCNd23XasXFJ3hcX531NG5Ic93ARilbbvSNcGsJI7CkRyjJbh2R4npcbh3tIWgYZKG9lSlYKpGN1X5Qcn3gFCsdXl2NV3yXclm592ybK6CVkWpbOp3RJ3lXd0HxVWydbhiZAWkZYk299VuZO0wF_G_Z

now I need to to decode using function decode64 but like [link](http://i60.tinypic.com/2euomzq.png)
because can't see the full decode64, why?

Comment: I've tried using multiple tools to decode the string you posted. I don't understand what the link you posed have got to do with it. The best idea I have is for you to try to change encoding, and also to check if this is indeed the full encoded string to decode.